# How to emit socket.io event from express controller on typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, socket.io

I'm learning socket.io and typescript. I'm currently building an app where I want to emit event on databases changes to the client.For the backend, I'm using Express, typescript and nodeJS

I've looked on a lot of posts but I don't understand how I can access my io instance to be able to emit my event from my controller functions. Also most examples are on javascript which is more confusing.

Currently in my app.ts I have the following configuration. How can I move my addOnlineHandler, logOutHandler and sendNotificationHandler in my controller functions to be able to emit event on database change directly from createOrder function of the controller ?

I've tried importing all orderHandler function in the controller but it's not working. I'm unable to access the io instance to emit events.

```
app.ts

import  express  from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import userRoute from './routes/user'
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { createServer } from "http";
import { Server,Socket } from "socket.io";
import {addOnlineShopHandler,logOutHandler, sendNotificationHandler} from "./socket/orderHandler";


dotenv.config();
const app = express();

const httpServer = createServer(app);

const io = new Server(httpServer, {
    cors:{
        origin:"*"
    }
});

const onConnection = (socket:Socket) => {
    addOnlineShopHandler(socket)
    logOutHandler(socket)
    sendNotificationHandler(socket)
    
  }

io.on("connection",onConnection)


httpServer.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log('Backend server is running')
});

const connectToDatabase = async (dbConnectionString:string) => {
    await mongoose.connect(dbConnectionString)
    console.log('Connection to DB sucess')
}

connectToDatabase(`${process.env.MONGO_URI}`).catch(err => console.log(err))

app.use('/api/users',userRoute)
```

My controller file where I need to be able to emit event when order is created.

```
orderController.ts

import { RequestHandler } from "express";


export const createOrder:RequestHandler = async (req, res) => {
    // I want to use socket.io in this function 
    // emit event when order created 


}
```

My orderHandler file.

```
orderHandler.ts

import { Server,Socket } from "socket.io";

interface IOnlineShop {
    shopId:string, 
    socketId:string
}

let onlineShop:IOnlineShop[] = []

export const addOnlineShopHandler = (socket:Socket) => {
    console.log('someone is in')
    
    const addNewShop = (shopId:string, socketId:string) => {
        !onlineShop.some((currentShop) => currentShop.shopId === shopId) && onlineShop.push({shopId,socketId})
    }
    const newShopConnected = (shopId:string) => {
        addNewShop(shopId,socket.id)
    }

    socket.on('newShopConnected',newShopConnected)

}

export const logOutHandler = (socket:Socket) => {

    const removeShop = (socketId:string) => {
        onlineShop = onlineShop.filter((currentShop)=>{currentShop.socketId !== socketId})
        console.log('someone is out')
    }
    socket.on('disconnect',removeShop)
    
}


export const sendNotificationHandler = (socket:Socket) =>{
    const getUser = (shopId:string) =>{
        return onlineShop.find((currentShop) => currentShop.shopId === shopId)}
    const sendNotification = (data:any) =>{
        const receiver = getUser('randomshopId')
        console.log(receiver)
    }

    socket.on("sendNotif",sendNotification)
}
```

I've looked theses posts and still can't get around the solution, maybe using typescript is what is confusing me. Any help or explanation of the workflow would be appreciated. [how to use socket.io in controller file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46448729/how-to-use-socket-io-in-controller-file?rq=1) [Use socket.io in controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19559135/use-socket-io-in-controllers)
[Socket.IO + Express framework | Emit/Fire From Express Controller & Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36904048/socket-io-express-framework-emit-fire-from-express-controller-router)

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach `io` to the app object:

```
app.set('io', io);
```

You can then access it from within controllers with `req.app.get('io')`

Comment: Thank you for the answer it seems to be working for emitting! But I can't take event from the client inside the controller. Do you happen to now why io.sockets.on is not getting data from client ?

Comment: To set a listener inside a controller (which I do not know if it is good practice or not) you need to attach the `socket` object to the app inside your `onConnection` function. Then you can access this socket object inside the controller and set a listener on it.

Comment: However I think you should never do this as it adds a listener every time the controller gets called. Maybe socketio rooms can help you.